# lift can't handle diacritics

Tags: scala, jakarta-ee, glassfish, lift, diacritics

I'm developing a web app with `Lift Framework`, `GlassfishV3` and there is a problem with diacritics in my app. I do just value binding to model and when I log the value from input text field, the diacritics letters are already broken. Where could possibly be the problem?

```
     bind("entry",content,
              "place" -> SHtml.text(lib.place, lib.place=_),
              "submit" -> SHtml.submit("Kaboom", () => {
                    Logger.getAnonymousLogger.severe(lib.place)
                    Service.library.save(lib)})
        )
```

It's probably a general java problem, not limited to `Lift`.
I enter `š` and I see `Å¡` as the output from logger.

Comment: Where exactly are you entering `š`? I suspect wrong text encoding for that file (if it is in a file)

Comment: i enter this in a `<input type="text" />` field, then the value is processed by framework

Comment: As the problem can only be guessed right now, maybe you should consider pushing a minimal example to a public repository.

Comment: I found that I have diacritics issues even with maven's 43. archetype in current catalog : `lift-archetype-jpa-basic_2.8.1`, so you can try this, I deploy in on `GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 (build 22)`. When I put some diacritics value in f.e. add author field, like `čřšť`, I see then `ÄÅÅ¡Å¥` in authors list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so one option to get `UTF-8` encoding is to specify encoding in `sun-web.xml` file like this:

```
<sun-web-app error-url="">
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
</sun-web-app>
```

the other option is to set encoding in lift bootstrapping class:
`def boot {
    LiftRules.early.append(makeUtf8)
}
private def makeUtf8(req: HTTPRequest) {
    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
}`

Answer (score 3):

Would it make you feel better or worse to know that the source of your entire problem is located between the keyboard and the back of your chair?

Here's what happened:

You wanted to print out š, a [lower-case s-with-caron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0), which is represented in [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) by the number 0x161.  You printed it out to a file, and your I/O system dutifully (and correctly) encoded it in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as 0xC5, 0xA1.  Then you asked view to that file *without explaining to your viewing program that it was a UTF-8 file*.  Your viewing program, whatever it was, interpreted the file as [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1), a very common, if somewhat elderly, format.  The 0xC5 was displayed as Å, [A-with-a-ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85), and the 0xA1 as ¡, an [inverted exclamation mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_question_and_exclamation_marks).

To summarize, there's nothing wrong with the output, there's just something wrong with the way you are looking at it.  Bring the log up in an editor and set the encoding to UTF-8 or bring it up in a web browser and select View / Character Encoding / UTF-8 .

Comment: yes, I'm viewing the page in firefox with UTF-8 encoding and I still don't see the characters right.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the clue to this might be the browser. What encoding does the browser assume for the page? Do you have an encoding meta-tag in the head; like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This could well be a problem in the logger or your console. Try logging to a file and opening that in an editor you know can handle UTF8

Comment: I tried to open glassfish's `server.log`, but the characters look still bad.